# How to achieve good receive SNR with FDD outdoor?

Tags: amplifier, rf, filter, radio, sdr

I'm trying to set up an eNB with srsRAN for outdoor usage in a small area with a USRP B210 SDR as RF frontend. To this aim, I'm using two amplifiers: MiniCircuits ZX60-V63+ PA in TX and ZX60-33LNR-S+ LNA in RX. I notice some severe deterioration of the uplink SNR when I use both amplifiers, while the SNR is pretty high when I use only the RX amplifier.

I'm not using any RX filter, so that could be one reason. Nonethless, I'm not sure if a filter would be sharp enough to block the interference from the TX amplifier.

I believe I could use a duplexer to decouple the TX and RX, though I'm not familiar with this kind of setups. Do you have any suggestions to improve the outdoor performance?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your TX Amplifier output noise skirts are likely overwhelming the receiver noise figure. You’ll need a band specific duplexer to provide isolation between the two.